# Pymongo query to get the latest document from the collection in Mongodb using Python

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am using `pymongo` and have below query to get the documents from a collection:

```
coll_employee = db.get_collection('employeeDetails')
query1 = [{'$match': {'EmployeeId': ObjectId('5edde542f6468910e080e462')}}]
document = coll_employee.aggregate(query1)
tmp1_list = []
for i in document:
    tmp1_list.append(i)
print(tmp1_list)
```

I am making a query based on `EmployeeId` which is an `ObjectId`. Running above code, I am getting all the documents of the collection. Is there any way we can only get the latest document which was created. Please help. Thanks

Comment: do you have a field like `updated_at` or something?

Comment: @KuldeepSinghSidhu Yes I do have a `created` field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PyMongo's syntax is little bit different than Mongo Shell's syntax. You don't need to use aggregation for this, a simple `find()` method will can do the work along with `sort()` and `limit()` methods. Below query will be helpful:

```py
db.coll_employee.find().sort('_id',-1).limit(1)
```

You can use any field, which gets incremented as we insert, like you were saying in comments, you have `created` field. So, instead of `_id`, you can use this field.

Comment: Note that `_id` may not be sorted in insertion order for documents inserted during the same second.

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can do a sort by ObjectID ( -1 ) if you want the latest record and then use the limit operation to retrieve just the first record .

It's like running the following query on your collection

```
db.coll_employee.select({'$match': {'EmployeeId': ObjectId('5edde542f6468910e080e462')}}).sort('_id':-1).limit(1)
```

Comment: Where should I include `sort` and `limit` in my query.?

Comment: I am getting this error `TypeError: 'Collection' object is not callable. If you meant to call the 'select' method on a 'Collection' object it is failing because no such method exists.`

Comment: apologies . I mixed up my SQL work with Mongo . In Mongo the equivalent of select is find . So the statement given below by S Andrew  is correct . 

My Version : 

db.coll_employee.find({'$match': {'EmployeeId': ObjectId('5edde542f6468910e080e462')}}).sort('_id':-1).limit(1)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution which worked for me:

```
query1 = {'EmployeeId': ObjectId('5edde542f6468910e080e462')}
document = coll_employee.find(query1).sort('_id', 1).limit(1)
```